# codenameone DeviceCalendar.getInstance().dc.getCalendars() is returning null on device

Tags: codenameone

Been struggling a couple of hours now with Device Calendar. It can not return any calendars that are on the device. I added the following permissions on the build hints in case it needed that.

android.permission.READ_CALENDAR
android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR

The following is my code for this

```
 DeviceCalendar dc = DeviceCalendar.getInstance();
 dc.getCalendars();
```

Its returning a null. This means i can't read or write to  the device calendars.

Comment: Permissions should be added automatically with the current version. Did you install via the extension manager? Are you running on the device?

Comment: Yes i added the CN1Calendar lib. I am running on an android phone and it returns null

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke `hasPermissions()` which will prompt for permission first and then you will be granted/denied permission to access the calendar.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have checked for permissions and been granted but i am still getting a null pointer exception

Comment: Did you check for permission by calling that method before? It needs to do the prompt first. Are you sure you got a null pointer because of that? On which OS version?